# Looking for idioms

Tags: expressions, idioms, slang

Is there an idiom for someone who's doing you a favor with someone else’s property or money?

Comment: I think you'll need to expand on what you mean by doing you a favor with someone else’s property or money. Are they a [fence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fence_(criminal))?

Comment: Perhaps a [moocher](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Moocher).

Answer (score 1):

If the someone else was not willfully donating the money to the someone, maybe: *rob Peter to pay Paul*:

> To harm one person in order to do good to another; by extension, to
> use money or resources set aside for one purpose for a different
> one.
>  <sub>Source:
> [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/rob--peter--to--pay--paul)</sub>

Your benefactor was robbing Peter (someone with money) to pay Paul (you).